# HTTP 422 Error with JSON & jQuery + Human API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the Human API found here: https://docs.humanapi.co/docs/connect-backend

At one point in connecting to the API, I need to send data back to them as JSON. I get a JSON object called `sessionTokenObject` which contains this:

```
{
  humanId: "1234567890",
  clientId: "abcdefg",
  sessionToken: "9876zyx",
}
```

To which I'm supposed to add a `clientSecret`. Essentially, I'm taking what's in the JSON object, converting it individual variables, passing them through to another page via URL parameters and then reconstructing everything so that I can add the `clientSecret` like so:

```
$pop_clientid = $_GET['clientid'];
$pop_humanid = $_GET['humanid'];
$pop_userid = $_GET['userid'];
$pop_sessiontoken = $_GET['clientid'];

$my_sessiontokenobject = '{
    humanId: "'.$pop_humanid.'",
    clientId: "'.$pop_clientid.'",
    sessionToken: "'.$pop_sessiontoken.'",
    clientSecret: "thesecretgoeshere"
}'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'https://user.humanapi.co/v1/connect/tokens',
          data: '<?php echo $my_sessiontokenobject; ?>',
          success: null,
          dataType: 'application/json'
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I don't wrap the `data` value in the `.ajax()` call in apostrophes, I get a 422 error back from https://user.humanapi.com/v1/connect/tokens

If I do, I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error.

Can anyone see what's wrong with my code, or perhaps even tell me if trying to recreate a JSON object and then pass it back via `.ajax()` in the manner I am is just completely incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: (Returns a 404 Not found error, but it seems that it is in their side)

```
connectBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var opts = {
    // grab this from the app settings page
    clientId: clientId,
    // can be email or any other internal id of the user in your system
    clientUserId: clientUserId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    finish: function(err, sessionTokenObject) {
        console.log(sessionTokenObject);
      // When user finishes health data connection to your app
      // `finish` function will be called.
      // `sessionTokenObject` object will have several fields in it.
      // You need to pass this `sessionTokenObject` object to your server
      // add `CLIENT_SECRET` to it and send `POST` request to the `https://user.humanapi.co/v1/connect/tokens` endpoint.
      // In return you will get `accessToken` for that user that can be used to query Human API.

      sessionTokenObject.clientSecret = clientSecret;

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: sessionTokenObject,
        });
      });


      // clientId=ceb8b5d029de3977e85faf264156a4e1aacb5377&humanId=f54fa4c56ca2538b480f90ed7b2c6d22



     //    $.post(url, sessionTokenObject, function(res){
     //     console.log(res);
        // });



    },
    close: function() {
      // do something here when user just closed popup
      // `close` callback function is optional
    }
  }
  HumanConnect.open(opts);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mario800ml - would this be considered doing it "client side" or server side? I ask because I assume this is all client side, but it's very similar to their node.js example given on their website, however when I speak to their support team they tell me that this should all be done server side.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it ultimately did answer the question of how to do this more efficiently. If anyone else is using the human API, and stumbles on this post, note that you can't actually do what I'm trying to do here - everything has to be server side, not client side. The developers pointed me toward this which proved quite useful: https://github.com/choccybiccy/humanapi

Answer (score 0):

Human API Code for Testing, this code generates accessToken from Human API Developer Side but its not coming as in response while i execute this code

```
<script src='https://connect.humanapi.co/connect.js'></script>
<script>
var options = {
    clientUserId: encodeURIComponent('email'), //Unique ID of user on your system (we send this back at the end)
    clientId: '',
    publicToken: '',
    finish: function (err, sessionTokenObject) {
        /* Called after user finishes connecting their health data */
        //POST sessionTokenObject as-is to your server for step 2.
        console.log(sessionTokenObject);
        sessionTokenObject.clientSecret  = 'Client Secret Key';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://user.humanapi.co/v1/connect/tokens',
            method: 'POST',
            data: sessionTokenObject
        })
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // show the response
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(data.success);
                    } else {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }

                })
                .fail(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // just in case posting your form failed
                    alert("Posting failed.");

                });

        // Include code here to refresh the page.
    },
    close: function () {
        /* (optional) Called when a user closes the popup 
         without connecting any data sources */
        alert('user clicked on close Button');
    },
    error: function (err) {
        /* (optional) Called if an error occurs when loading
         the popup. */
    }
}
function openHumanApiModel() {
    HumanConnect.open(options);
}
</script>
```